# Handle click event with Gridster

Tags: jquery, gridster

Using [Gridster](http://gridster.net/), I can bind events on start and stop dragging. But how can I bind event to a single click on an item? I need to be able to select an item in order to remove it, or to set some properties to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery click events to bind single click on an element. [Here is an example of the same.](http://jsfiddle.net/paDE7/11/) Following is the general layout of the binding.

```
       $('.layout_block').click(function () {
                //function to set some properties using $(this)
                //setting an identifier to remove the element
       }
```

Here `layout_block` is the class to all the elements of gridster.

Comment: That will not work on elements added after initialization. I tried using `$('.layout_block').on('click', function() {});`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Any which method you use, the new elements will have to be register their eventhandler, which involves re-initializing the .click() function.

Comment: Ahh, of course! Now it works: `var widget = gridster.add_widget('<li>foo</li>', size_x, size_y);                 widget.click(myFunction);`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`javascript
$(document).on("click", ".layout_block", handler);`

worked for me, even for widgets that are added with `gridster.add_widget();`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working code.

```
$(".gridster ul li button.close").click(function () {
        gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
});
```

So Inside my Li element, I have a button with `class=close` on detecting the click event, I call the widget method `gridster.remove_widget` and pass the html element for it to remove.

Happy Coding :)